# PHP error_reporting: what does "reporting" mean?

Tags: php

I have a PHP REST API endpoint that throws an error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Accessing static property...as non static in...
```

with the default `error_reporting` value but returns a correct value if `error_reporting` is set to 1, which I believe is `E_ERROR`.

Doesn't error_reporting just control the logging? This seems to control whether the exception is thrown as well, allowing the code to continue as normal.

I come from a Java background, used to using Logback and similar logging frameworks. In these frameworks, the log level refers to a filter for the recipient of the logs, commonly a log file. A log level X means that messages need to be at least level X (or lower than, I forget which) to be logged, but it doesn't affect whether the exception is thrown to begin with.

I had assumed that this was the case with PHP's `error_reporting`, however, based on the above behavior I am not sure.

I've looked through the PHP docs, but I haven't found a detailed explanationof how `error_reporting` works

So, my question: What does "reporting" mean here? Does `error_reporting` control more besides which exceptions/errors are logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error_reporting` is a bit different with the log level, the argument is a set of toggles for each error type.

For example `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` only reports errors and `error_reporting(E_NOTICE)` only reports notices and `error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_NOTICE)` reports both errors and notices but doesn't report warnings.

FYI the error level of this message *"Accessing static property...as non static in..."* is `E_STRICT` in PHP 5 and `E_NOTICE` in PHP 7 by default.

This is weired because you got an exception, I guess the problem that changes the behaviour of the error is in your [error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: Thanks, you were right, we had a custom error handler borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814000/356887). As my comment there says, it seems to change the default behavior of `error_reporting`.